# Не изменяется размер ContentControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть на форме у MasterWindow.xaml - ContentControl

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                        Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Таким образом заполняю контент

```
var control = new DiagnosticsView(); //Создаю представление xaml
        _masterWindow.Content = control; // Помещаю его в контент
        control.ViewModel = newView; //В представление передаю ViewModel для вызова команд
```

В итоге, DiagnosticsView должен быть вложен в MasterWindow и иметь размеры 100на100, но он расстягивается на все окно.
Вот результат, MasterWindow с нужным меню - нет.
[image: Рис 1]

Если поменяю размер дочернего представления, то он уменьшится, а фон будет белым.

[image: Рис 2]

Content занимает всю область, как сделать, чтобы было видно MasterWindow?

Comment: `Content="{Binding}"` - это зачем? куда привязка?

Comment: MasterWindow - это вкладка "Выбор типа диагностики"?  Или это область с вкладками? Мне кажется, что тут проблема с разметкой.

Comment: @aepot Видел пример в интернете такой, без привязки работает точно также

Comment: @AB Нет MasterWindow у меня жирная синяя рамка с кнопками, ее нет

Comment: Слишком мало сведений, чтобы разобраться.